# how can i use neutral network with gray-scale images in keras

Tags: keras, neural-network

I am trying to train on gray images. The `batch_size = 32, image size = (48*48)`.
I define my network `input_shape = (48,48,1)`. I get an error like below when I train the network.

Error :

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_17_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 48, 48)

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(48,48,1)
                )
         )
```

Comment: anyone can help me? my English is so bad ,sorry

Comment: Your input should have shape (32, 48, 48, 1),  you can reshape with np.reshape

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say you have `1000` training images where each image is `48x48` greyscale. After you have loaded the images into a numpy array, you will end up with the shape : `(1000, 48, 48)`.

This essentially means you have `1000` elements in your array and each element is a `48x48` matrix.

Now in order to feed this data to train a `CNN`, you have to reshape this list to `(1000, 48, 48, 1)` where `1` stands for channel dimension. Since you are having greyscaled images you have to use `1`. If it was RGB it will be `3`.

Consider the toy example given below,

```
x_train = np.random.rand(1000, 48, 48) #images
y_train = np.array([np.random.randint(0, 2) for x in range(1000)]) # labels

# simple model

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(48,48,1)
                )
         )

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# fitting model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

This will throw an error,

> Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 48, 48)

To fix it reshape the `x_train` like this,

`x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1)`

Now fit the model,

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

Epoch 1/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.7177
Epoch 2/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 882us/step - loss: 0.6762
Epoch 3/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 870us/step - loss: 0.5882
Epoch 4/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 888us/step - loss: 0.4588
Epoch 5/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 906us/step - loss: 0.3272
Epoch 6/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 910us/step - loss: 0.2228
Epoch 7/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 895us/step - loss: 0.1607
Epoch 8/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 879us/step - loss: 0.1172
Epoch 9/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 886us/step - loss: 0.0935
Epoch 10/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 888us/step - loss: 0.0638
```

Comment: nice to hear it helped

Answer (score 1):

Your input should have 4 dimenstions even if it is gray scale. So, you can use [`np.reshape(input,(32,48,48,1))`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) or [`np.expand_dims(input,axis=3)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your images should be reshaped to `(sample_length, 48, 48, 1)` and your `input_shape = (48, 48, 1)`

```
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
    input_shape = (48, 48, 1)
```

You can look at the MNIST example [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py), which is similar to your case.